# Faster way to find zeros of quadratic equations.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I use 'splitting the middle term' method to find zeros of a quadratic equation. Sometimes it takes a lot of time to split it. 
As for example:
\begin{align}
   & x^2+5x-1476=0 \\
   & x^2+41x-36x-1476=0 \\
   & x(x+41)-36(x+41)=0 \\
   & (x+41)(x-36)=0 \\
   & x=-41, \, 36
\end{align}

Is there any trick to split the middle term, or do you have any faster way to find the zeros.

Comment: The zeroes of $x^2+px+q=0$ are $\frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2$ in constant time

Comment: So you need to **see** that $1476$ factors into $41$ and $36$?

Comment: Yes, any trick to get it faster.

Comment: @GufranMozahir I don't mean it rudely, but that is a trick in mine eyes at best and a less useful method.

Comment: No, I didn't take it rudely instead I am thankful to you that you gave your time on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether any of the previous answers really address the question, which is to have a *trick* to solve the equation $x^2+5x-1476=0$. Of course, the explicit formula for the roots gives the answer, but I would no qualify this as a trick, but as a generic solution for this type of problem.

There is however a trick, if you assume that, as most of the elementary questions of this type, the equation has *integer solutions*. In this case, you can write 
$x^2+5x-1476= (x+a)(x-b)$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. It follows $ab = 1476$ and $a-b = 5$. Now comes the trick: the prime decomposition of $1476$ is $41 \times 2^2 \times 3^2$ (easy to find), which let you few possibilities for $a$. Just try the first one, $a = 41$, then $b = 2^2 \times 3^2 = 36$. Bingo! one gets $a-b = 5$, so we are done.

Comment: Thankyou J.-E. Pin this is indeed a good hack.

Answer (score 2):

The best way in my opinion is using the quadratic formula,

Given  a quadratic $ ax^2+bx+c =0$

$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

You could also try [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square),in order to get the solution

Answer (score 1):

When you split a polynomial as 
$$x^2+px+q=x^2+ax+bx+ab=(x+a)(x+b)$$

you readily see that the roots are $-a$ and $-b$. Thus, such splitting is equivalent to finding roots.

By the way, there's an explicit formula for the roots:

$$\frac{-p\pm \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$$

Comment: Thankyou lisyarus. But finding the roots as in my question: √5929 is also lengthy.

Comment: Method 1: Use a calculator. Method 2: Find a number close to $5929$ whose square root you know. E.g. $\sqrt{4900}=70$ or $\sqrt{6400}=80$. Also consider that if $n^2=5929$, then  $n$ must end in a $3$ or $7$ if it is a whole number. Since you know its between $70$ and $80$, you can check $73^2=5329$ by hand and $77^2=5929$ which you seek.

Comment: Precisely explained, thankyou again. This helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way what i know is the substitution $$x=t-\frac{b}{2a}$$ then we get
$$t^2+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{bt}{a}+\frac{bt}{a}-\frac{b^2}{2a^2}+\frac{c}{a}=0$$ and we get $$t^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}=0$$ to solve. And you get no middle term.

Answer (score 0):

I am too lazy to memorize the $p$-$q$-formula, I like completing the square, 
thus applying $a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a+b)^2$:
\begin{align}
0 
&= x^2+5x-1476 \\
&= x^2+5x + \biggl(\frac{5}{2}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{5}{2}\biggr)^2 - 1476 \\
&= \biggl(x + \frac{5}{2}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{5929}{4}\biggr) \iff \\
\pm \sqrt{\frac{5929}{4}} &= x + \frac{5}{2} \\
\pm \frac{77}{2} &= x + \frac{5}{2} \iff \\
x &= \frac{-5 \pm 77}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thankyou mvw, it helps..

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, use the Quadratic Formula:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Here 
$$x=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{25-4(1)(-1476)}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{5929}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-5\pm 77}{2}$$
$$x=36, x=41$$ from changing between the $\pm$ between a $+$ and a $-$

Comment: Thankyou Rhys Hughes

Comment: No worries Gufran.